# Getting items that referenced an object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
// PRODUCT MODEL
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    colors: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Color",
      },
    ],
    sizes: {
      type: Array,
      default: [
        { id: 1, size: "XS" },
        { id: 2, size: "S" },
        { id: 3, size: "M" },
        { id: 4, size: "L" },
        { id: 5, size: "XL" },
        { id: 6, size: "XXL" },
      ],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);


const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
export default Product;



// CATEGORY MODEL
const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
  },
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: true, toObject: true }
);

CategorySchema.virtual("items").get(async function () {
  return await CategorySchema.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Product",
        localField: "category",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "items",
      },
    },
  ]);
});

const Category = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
export default Category;
```

Hello, please i'm trying to get list of items that referenced each categoryid on the product model, i want to add the result as a virtual field called "count" from the category model and not the product model. i'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'transform' in true".

i want to get the result the way it was done in this example from mongodb doc about inventory and orders but i'm getting "items: {}". docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup

Comment: use poplulate method

Comment: Yes, if i wanted to get the category objects from the Product model i can use populate, but here i want to get the products that referenced each category, i want the result to show as for instance productCount while querying for all categories (sample result : {"name": "men", "count": 33})

Comment: can you post an code sinppet of desired output

Comment: for instance if i query GET / http://localhost:8800/api/categories, the result should be  [{"name": "men", "count": 33}]

Comment: you can do `product.find().populate({path:"category", match:{name:"<value>"}})`;

Comment: this returns an empty object: items: {}, i called it on the category model , CategorySchema.virtual("items").get(function () { product.find().populate({path:"category", match:{name:"<value>"}})}

Comment: you should call it on the product model, it will return all the products with category men and you can send the count as a response for the API

Comment: there is no way to call it from the category model?

Comment: i want to get the result the way it was done in this example from mongodb doc about inventory and orders but i'm getting "items: {}".   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

```js
router.get(
  "/counts",
  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const stats = await Category.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "products",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "category",
          as: "count",
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1,
          image: 1,
          count: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $isArray: "$count" },
              then: { $size: "$count" },
              else: "NA",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
    if (!stats) {
      return res.status(404).json("No data found");
    }
    res.status(200).json(stats);
  })
);
```

For anyone that is trying to achieve the result i wanted, i used Category.aggregate on the category route instead of creating a virtual field from the category model.